# add ul element after li element dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have an unordered list like this:

```
<ul>
    <li class="foo">Item 1</li>
    <li class="bar">Item 2</li>
</ul>
```

I want to dynamically add a ul after each li in my list so I have something like this

```
<ul class="mylist">
    <li class="foo">Item 1</li>
    <ul></ul>
    <li class="bar">Item 2</li>
    <ul></ul>
</ul>
```

The uls must be loaded via ajax.
Any help on how I can do this please?

Comment: You are trying to create an invalid document structure. That won't be possible. You can add the `ul` *inside* each `li` though.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to append the UL to each of the LI, and not after each LI as that is invalid html and wont work.

```
jQuery.ajax({
     ...
     dataType:'html',
     success:function(data){
       //Assuming jQuery ajax dataType is set to HTML
       jQuery("li.foo").append(data);
     }
});
```

Comment: @dudewad i see jquery as tag, don't you?

Comment: he has tagged this with jquery so i think so

Comment: Ah my bad, sorry didn't see the tag :/

Answer (score 0):

`$("ul.list li").append("<ul></ul>");` works as well if you give the `<ul>` a class of `list`.